# Unable to reuse the java code string variable to another request in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a string variable which is returned from java code and I want to use it in a POST request like below:

```
And request {data:'string',data2:'{data3:'6DW7926NC7KMQ',data4:'#(funReturnedStringVal)'}'                                                  
     }
```

The issue is when I run it I get invalid data because funReturnedStringVal does not keep the value which I get from the java code. I could print the value of funReturnedStringVal but when I used it in another request like above I get the response as above i.e. the variable does not replace with the actual value.

I tried but could not get it right so please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make this change:

```
And request { data: 'string', data2: { data3: '6DW7926NC7KMQ', data4: '#(funReturnedStringVal)' } }
```

Your mistake is you put some part of the JSON within string quotes. Then Karate will not process embedded expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I did it the way you just asked to change but still, I get invalid data object.
I tried it before but could not get the proper response so finally, I put it here.

Comment: @RanjanGupta yeah yeah I believe you. now you need to follow this process, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I think I am doing everything right so far coz I asked the developer and they gave the signal to ask you. 
Actually, I need to pass paypalPaymentId value which I get from the successful payment made on PayPal.
Having said that, I am getting the value from PayPal URL but when I passed that in the request then the problem occurs. Anyways, I will submit the issue.

Comment: Done. The issue is solved. I had to convert the string variable funReturnedStringVal again to karate string like below:
string strVal = funReturnedStringVal. Thanks for the quick reply @Peter Thomas

Answer (score 1):

@Ranjan - I just came across your post about reusing java code and it seems you solved your issue. However, I was checking to see whether your json is in correct format or not?, I see your JSON structure is incorrect. Can you please check the attachment and verify from your side too. Maybe this will help others too, and my confidence is that any person having JSON issues will thoroughly verify JSON request structure by using any of the json validation tools that are available online.

[image: JSON structure]